# Assigning individual elements in a vector to new variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

Let's just say I have a matrix:

```
a=[1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
```

I would like to assign all the elements in the second row to separate variables like:

```
x=4 y=5 z=6
```

When I type...

```
[x,y,z] = a(1,:) or [x,y,z] = a(:)
```

...it throws an error message displaying that

> "Indexing cannot multiple results"

Answer (score 2):

Use cell arrays -

```
a_cell = num2cell(a(2,:));
[x y z] = a_cell{:}
```